# How to get first non NaN value in DF and replace all other values as NaN in the DF

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to find the first non-NaN value in each row and then replace rest all the values in that DF with NaN.
Ex:

```
1      2    3      4
NaN    5    7      11
NaN   NaN   20     9
NaN   NaN  NaN     15
```

Thanks

O/P should be:

```
1     NaN   NaN    NaN
NaN   5     NaN    NaN
NaN   NaN   20     NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN    15
```

Comment: If you don't want to do that manually, I suggest writing some code. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Import packages.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Create the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    1: [2, 5, np.nan, np.nan],
    2: [3, 7, 20, np.nan],
    3: [4, 11, 9, 15]
})
```

Find the index of the first non-NaN value in each row (axis=1).

```
first_valid_index = df.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

Use `iloc` to replace the rest of the values with NaN.

```
# Iterate through each row
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    
    # If the last element of each row is a non-NaN value 
    if first_valid_index[i] == df.shape[1] - 1:
        continue
    
    # Update the rest of the values with NaN values
    else:
        df.iloc[i, first_valid_index[i+1]:] = np.nan
```

Print the result.

```
print(df)
```